# 'lli' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: java, llvm, antlr

```
I am new to LLVM, i am trying to execute LLVM bitcode using java in windows .
```

E:\antlr\stage2\loop>java -classpath E:\antlr\readwrite\antlr-4.7.1-complete.jar;. Main test.x > test.ll
Using above command  i am generating llvm bitcode, 
Getting error while trying to execute llvm bitcode
 E:\antlr\stage2\loop>lli test.ll
    'lli' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
`operable program or batch file`.**strong text**